# How would you create two select menus where select menu B's contents are dependent on select menu A's selection?

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, django

How do you create two select menus with one dict where select menu B has values that correspond and are dependent to the keys present in select menu A?

In my Django views.py, I've created a dictionary that has a lists of Projects as keys, and corresponding Tasks as values within the dictionary. It looks like the following

Project A: Task 1

Project A: Task 2

Project A: Task 3

Project B: Task 1

Project B: Task 2

Project C: Task 1

etc

I've been able to successfully pass this information into my Django template, but I can't wrap my head around how I can do what I need to do with the information.

I need to be able to take the information in the keys, ie the Projects, and create a drop down menu (A) which, when a key is selected, will display all of the corresponding tasks for the key in a second drop down menu (B)

I'm up to any kind of solution. I'm thinking about using jquery and hacking something together, but I'm really at a loss as to how to begin. Does anyone have experience with something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`django-autocomplete-light`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to do this. This basically provides autocompletion using a client library such as [`select2`](https://select2.github.io/). But it also provides a way to [filter results based on another field](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form).

You should likely also make a server verification in the form clean:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all())
    task = forms.Model.ChoicField(queryset=Task.objects.all())

    def clean(self):
        project = self.cleaned_data['project']
        task = self.cleaned_data['task']
        if task.project_id != project.pk:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "The selected task does not belong to the selected project.")
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I'll look into this asap

Comment: W O W thanks for that edit! Exactly what I need, thank you so much!